# MySQL: Only allow users to execute procedures, but avoid access to any other resources such as tables?

Tags: mysql

How can I tell MySQL that a given user is only allowed the execution of stored procedures, and not to read or write tables directly?

I want to limit the type and scope of all operations that a user can make in order to protect the database.

If there are better ways to do this I am also opened to suggestions :)

Thanks!

Comment: Create a new database a an put the stored procs in this schema. Then give the user only rigths to access this schema

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the table and procedure always can ACCESS them, create a another user for the Database Connection Pool of your program, grant execute to it.